# I need my main navbar to disapear and show the mobile menu after the window reaches a certain size

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

please help!!!

my main nav bar overlaps the text on the left and my right side nav disappears when the window gets resized i need the main nav to disappear and the mobile nav to show when the window gets resized or viewed from a mobile device...

please note im still new with coding so please explain in easy way for me to understand...

here is the link to my site: http://gerlagroofing.co.za/default.asp

Comment: Go through responsive web design basics : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/?hl=en . Use media query to change the main nav  to mobile view according to screen size.

Comment: that's not really what i needed but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You must look in @media Rules, that are used for make your design responsive, it make possible to make different css rule on different screen size.
For example you can hide you logo text on screen width less than 750px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  #header a{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You can discover and see examples of using media rules here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp